# Is this statement true? - The number of the subgroups(direct product)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For Let $A_i$ be the finite Abelian groups, $i=1,2,...n$

Say the Group, $A$ $s.t.A = \Pi _{i=1 }^{n}A_i$

Let  $|A_i|$(the order of the $A_i$) are pairwise relatively prime

(I.E. $gcd(|A_i|, |A_j|=1)$, $\forall i,j(\neq i ) $)

Then, Does This statement hold?

(The number of the Subgroups of the A) =  $\Pi _{i=1 }^{n}$(the number of subgroups of the $A_i$)

p.s.) My guess is true by fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

But I can't figure out the above is true or not .

Comment: Maybe let's answer this question first. By direct calculation or not. What are subgroups of $Z_k$ ?

Comment: @Jakobian,  The subgroups are $H = <d> s.t. d \vert k $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. One way to see why it is true is to define a map from the set of subgroups of $A$ to the Cartesian product of the set of subgroups of each $A_i$ by sending an $H \leq A$ to $(H_1,\ldots,H_n)$ where $H_i$ is the Hall $|A_i|$-subgroup of $H$.

Try to prove that this is a bijection between those two sets.